# How to conditionally include a specific tool in a jenkinsfile that is set in jenkins' global tool configuration?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to conditionally set the jdk version to be used in a generic pipeline used over multiple applications.

This code works:

```
  pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
            jdk 'AdoptOpenJDK 11'
    }
```

However i would like something like this:

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        if (jdkVersion) {
            jdk 'AdoptOpenJDK 11'
        } else {
            jdk 'AdoptOpenJDK 11'
        }
    }
```

The first jdk version should be variable, but to be sure that's not the problem I've kept those the same for both cases. However this code gives the following errors:

```
No tools specified @ line 24, column 9.
       tools {
```

That makes it seem like I can't use an if clause at this point, but what other options are there?

Comment: You may want to just make this a parameter.

Comment: Try to use ternary operator, e. g. `jdk jdkVersion ? 'foo' : 'bar'` or call a function e. g. `jdk getJdkVersion()`, which can be defined before or after the `pipeline{}` block.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way to do this in jenkins, but at least it works. Define a variable beforehand, don't bother with a if/else in tools.

```
def jdkversion = configJdkVersion ? 'configJdkversion' : 'default jdk version'

pipeline {
   tools {
      jdk jdkversion
```